# jQuery noConflict after existing jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery

I am working on a site made in Magento and I need to add my own jQuery. The problem is, the site already contains a plugin (ig lightbox2) that uses its own version of jQuery (1.6.2).

So I have added jQuery 1.11 and my script file to the footer and set it up like this:

```
$.noConflict();
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {

//Script Here

}); //End of No Conflict
```

However this causes parts of the Lightbox plugin to stop working with the error:

```
jQuery.easing[jQuery.easing.def] is not a function.
```

Is there a way to add my jQuery 1.11 without affecting the plugin?

Edit:
I have changed the plugin settings to not use easing and it avoids the problem, and I can keep my scripts in the footer. However for future reference, if I were to put my scripts first in the head how would I make them work properly?

This is an example of the preloaded js I am working around:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com.au/skin/js/prototype/prototype.js,/js/lib/ccard.js,/js/prototype/validation.js,/js/scriptaculous/builder.js,/js/scriptaculous/effects.js,/js/scriptaculous/dragdrop.js,/js/scriptaculous/controls.js,/js/scriptaculous/slider.js,/js/varien/js.js,/js/varien/form.js,/js/varien/menu.js,/js/mage/translate.js,/js/mage/cookies.js,/js/varien/product.js,/js/varien/configurable.js,/js/calendar/calendar.js,/js/calendar/calendar-setup.js,/js/esl/jquery-1.8.3.min.js,/js/esl/no_conflict.js,/skin/frontend/default/default/esl/custom_option_variations/js/select_variation.js,/skin/frontend/base/default/ig_lightbox2/js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js,/skin/frontend/base/default/ig_lightbox2/lightbox/js/jquery.lightbox-0.5.pack.js" ></script>
```

Comment: I am sure you have already checked this, but just in case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566595/can-i-use-multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page

Comment: you should know where to put the `noConflict()`, by just putting inside your body or head section without knowing where your plugin lightbox is called, that would be a problem. Just think that `noConflict()` will put your the above jquery instance in silent for the below code to prevent a conflict

Comment: @Alp The answer there requires the earlier version to be noConflict as well. I want to know if I can add my new script without changing what is already there.

Comment: `$.noConflict(true)(function ($) { /* 1.11 code here */ });`

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, you should be loading the noConflict-version first. So in your case, put 1.11 in the header, with the noConflict-script, before 1.6.2 and the lightbox scripts. That, I think, should work.

Comment: Moving my addition to the head before the plugin, makes the plugin work but my script doesn't...

Comment: What's your script exactly?
And are you using jQuery() instead of $() in the code that's supposed to use 1.11?

Comment: I have the Slick plugin within my noConflict script, and when it's in the header, this part no long works causing the rest of my script to not run.

Comment: Can you post your entire header (or at least everything that's javascript-related)?

Comment: Updated with js from head.